# 350 Request Limit for Instagram API

Tags: instagram

I have problem with huskies in my application. I can't like

I keep getting an error response, although the limit does not exceed 5000 likes. Anyone solved this problem ?

My app: instaflat.jit.su

Comment: Please provide the code you're working with, or at the very least the specific API end point that you're calling. Instagram rate-limits `likes` much lower than general API calls, somewhere in the vicinity of 100 per hour.

Comment: @r3mus Interesting. The Instagram API Documentation site only lists the limits on the # of requests, which at the time of this writing, is `a maximum 5000 requests per hour`. Are the other limits, such as the limit on # of `Likes` documented anywhere?

Comment: The rate limits are not well documented at all. You will find different limits for comments, likes, unlike, follows, and unfollowed. The only way I came across them is actually looking in that return header at the rate limit.

Comment: @r3mus TFTI! I didn't know that the return header contains rate limits. Good to know, so as to not accidentally violate and get banned!

Comment: You don't get violated or banned, but if your count exceeds the limit, you have to wait an hour to have it available again.

Comment: I know the block/unblock relationship rate limits are shared (probably also with follow/unfollow) and are at 160/hour.  The only way you can check if you have exceeded them is to call them, and calling them, even if it fails due to exceeding the rate limit, counts towards your rate limit.  So just a caveat - if you continually retry once you're rate limited you'll never get unlimited, so make sure you back off from rate limit errors.

Answer (score 1):

The rate limits for Instagram's API are not well documented at all. You will find different limits for comments, likes, unlike, follows, and unfollows.

The best way to determine the allowed rate limit for a particular call is to examine the HTTP request header with a tool like [POSTMAN](http://www.getpostman.com/) or even Instagram's [API Console](https://apigee.com/console/instagram).

Comment: +1 for the (`Response`) Headers. Though POSTMAN does not work with `OAuth2.0`... ;S

Comment: @TRNCFRMCN how so? I use several OAuth2 flows that work. Unless they're web client stuff, that's not going to work.

Comment: Ok, just based that on the selection menu, only OAuth1.0...(y)

Comment: @TRNCFRMCN maybe you're using an old version? The latest offline-chrome version from getpostman.com shows OAuth 2.0.

Comment: Oh, I installed the Chrome extension?!?

Comment: Yeah, they've got a standalone version now - not sure why they haven't removed the chrome extension. But it still is technically an extension anyway... kinda confusing lol.

Comment: Ok, more confusion: Go to the link you posted, watch the first pic: only OAuth1.0. Scroll down to **Authentication**: *OAuth 2 is on the way!* Click on **Docs**: OAuth2.0 in the menu header... ;)

Comment: @TRNCFRMCN LOL. Goofy. oh well.

Comment: Hey, funny, I was into a [**total other thing**](http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/) and found that: [**http://hurl.it**](http://hurl.it).

Comment: @TRNCFRMCN yea it works pretty well, but doesn't let you save API calls. That's what's nice about POSTMAN.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram has new API limits: 100 likes/hr 60 follows/unfollows/hr. That is only if you authenticate serverside and sign your headers. Check out the new authentication: http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/

I'm using it for my new site that automates likes/follows/unfollows, haven't had any problems works great. Check it out: http://instapromobiz.com